# C# -HttpWebRequest returns 400 Bad request when connecting to Report Server programmatically

Tags: c#, basic-authentication, ssrs-2012, http-status-code-401, http-status-code-400

I am  programmatically making a Http Web Request to Report Server from a asp net web page which is present in another remote machine for downloading the report (URL Access - SSRS)

when I directly type in the URL, browser asks me the  credentials, and when I type in the credentials the report gets downloaded automatically in browser,
but when I programmatically make the request, I get the below mentioned errors.

C# code :

```
string username="abc", password="123";
string url = @"http://ServerName/ReportingPath&Parameter1=123&rs:Format=PDF";
String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));                
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);                
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 11.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; " +
                "Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; " +  ".NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; " +
                "InfoPath.2)";                
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I get a  HTTP 400-bad-request when I supply username as "domain/abc" or "abc@domain", 
and It also comes when I place this statement

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username,password,domain);
```

instead of line->

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

If I supply username simply, stripping the domain, like username="abc", I get 401-Unauthorised error.

I don't get either of the errors 400 or 401 when I type in URL in the internet browser. I specify username as "domain/abc" and password as "123", when it asks for credentials

My webConfig file of report server is like this..

```
<Authentication>
<AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsBasic/>
</AuthenticationTypes>
<RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
<RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
<EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to set url as 
`http://abc:123@ServerName/ReportingPath&Parameter1=123&rs:Format=PDF` and without authentication.

It's part of [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) in HTTP.

Comment: Still it is not working. Getting the same error "401 Unauthorized" . Is there a way we can pass domain along with user name & password to the server?

Comment: [here](http://drayblog.gotdns.com/index.php/2012/09/25/sql-2008-ssrs-web-service-access-from-net/) you have a working example.

Comment: Its works fine.. Many thanks for the sample.. Much appreciated